# design 8-bit adder with 74LS83

Tags: digital-logic, integrated-circuit, circuit-design

How can I design a 8-bit adder with chip 74LS83?
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need to stack them like in the picture:

[image: Stacked]

Comment: And if one wants a skip-carry adder, they can add a 2nd upper-nibble adder and a multiplexer. In that configuration, the carry-in line of one of the upper adders is set to 0 (wire to GND)  and the other to 1 (wire to Vcc).  The outputs of both go to a multiplexer and the lower Carry-out drives the select line.

That improves the speed because the upper adder doesn't have to work twice before the result is valid. Switching is faster here than adding again.