# Is it possible to set starting count on binary counters like CD4020?

Tags: binary

Can I set starting count on binary counters like CD4020, CD4060?
Only solution I know is to use reset pin and increase the frequency till you get desired count then resume normal operation.
If there is no other solution then, is there simple circuit which can feed desired number of pulses to the binary counter?

Comment: "simple circuit to feed desired number of pulses" .... that would be a counter. There are loadable counters ... simply use them instead of the 4020.

Comment: *use reset pin and increase the frequency* You mean: Apply a reset and then apply a clock until the desired state is reached. There's no "increase the frequency". You want a function that these counters do not support (check the datasheet!), so the short answer is **no**.

Comment: Why do you need a fixed pulse count?   Normally You start from 0 then use gates to match count and either stop clock or Reset and count again to make a divide by N-1

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie we can feed pulses from faster external clock till we get the count then we switch back to normal internal or external clock.

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 I want to set the circuit to start as per preconditions given at the time and don't want it to stop till battery dies.

Comment: This might be a good opportunity to replace that stuff with a microcontroller.

Comment: Then what is it counting up for? to? why is it counting ? for what purpose?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you only have common gates to work with and want some preset value using NAND/NOR GATES to switch from a fast clock to a slow clock, then consider [this](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgDCDsB0BsBMBWMLVrARgKYFoAcIAzNIRhogCyIYCciesN8p8IybbYAUBrBSDkJh%20OWqxzNxYkBjDx%20GfhGXgOERGs0b1IAGYBDADYBnLOB7UBfAfBQCMhWDbsYQrdRdejITnBQKiwgL%20MiD8xHzwNGI0dNRRiLi2bFwA7gJCItbevtbc6TkCiL6Zqvn2PsEQgkGE7mkVJeKlNE7lftW2Adld5gUhfgEDikpcADL28ATw8vYYrNIqAC4ATgCuZtoNEmDTs6JTbrPcvM1B2Y4E1qwAJlgGa4ZLOIZYN6EqYNCYPAgZQa0MrACIDbvd9I9nq93q5Pt8ML8zuFmsCiKwwQ8ni83h8yvDETJfANidMQHdMVCcbC8T9Tv8RNJBKjREw3GTwZDsTCyuB8XSaiJAUyAqD2RSubjlHy-gLJgFLnK2eSIVjoZLebSZaVRLBqgqdRAMSrKdy4ZqkVYRPrrmLjRLqVLzfSMij5ejbZy1Q6NQj%20aU9ajDR7VVSeV8fgAlIEBRn6mZKVQUCDEQhh6CIbb62PM3jKTM53XRxXtLOHYUCQEl5lC62jAq1ouCer15l1It5ltXK2oyv5ght8t5PuqcttqsEeby1G5vpFmflxbD7N7OtFmvTw4nLVBSdzw5Gz2hs2%207cKQsLwsHkOmmkni3xosPq8m9Xhu-O5cyVnP%201pn4rQkBEgBYiQIZMhC4KNeCAkD7CCFQkyIEg0wzespDLbJd24ABJS17AoLIGVZKUNFQ4IhhjIJBnMcgvEwxx7AY0QGNcVhSO2BxfAwPAGSYzjZxwTCCPI-DRijDpnAnXxen4UjUE0KUaEgl1FWgg4CFkzh0AU3lyGiSgaAoIQmE8RiuNZHYY1ZViOAzABZMz7B4yZqm4hN4HTLgHOY6S7B8mxjjcTzvMwiyemgw1gqqSTookMcgvsmKWXEXoJAihKuAADyAjRpAoJxaA0fhZgABRWLBjGMAAdYxytMJYsqc1N8FcwgNBwSBIDCGQIH0AA7ABPGqAAc6qwBqgA)

Here from 5MHz to 5kHz

[image]

- disregard how I biased LEDs for 5V turn on. (I didn't want to clutter it with all the R's.

[See Rev A in Comments](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgTCDsB0BsYFYAMLVqQRgKYFoAcIC0AnAMwAsYxypskpxYSByhhSAUBrOSDqUl44MjPmFIRhojEjC8MvJCCUq2q9cs0I2AMwCGAGwDOWZVwQY%20PMSj4ZaNpZYjaEHAO58BQ6ziZKca05PYUE%20cgI-W0DFD3CApkjfRLMQiPjwyIVYgBk7MAIwOTsMCBEIVQAXACcAV1NtYJtC4uEC8GLObklvEF9aAmsIABMsfVqDSpwDLGGQS3VoTC54LzDiWC9YAg3wEFHxyenZ%20c0VJYwVnrCJLYJbkbG9CamZuYWzi6u1oXK7u1Ej0OrxOH3Oy26Pz4u3422hmyBzyOb1Oiwhq34YTakQG%20UK%20yeL2O7zOyi%20kMxv1gAVxwmpewOSJBJLRlwpvRi-05iKJKLBZPR1yEt1hOIgPORoNJSHJGN6NLhSglzNRn2WACUuX9RWJOppyEpSNBSNLoG4QrTtZb6U0dXSFVl2rbLe07btnXCcDDaUE4nb%20p7bh6xf8VH7cQGdptgyARRHYhbFf8g%20G4aUcWmbamCNwHfNRDGrXCign-t6007vpT5q7cemGYTJSy1Wy5WFc-8O8riarwa2hR1hcXit2%20abBVCiznAQTgT3%20TLlhbJPXOdizBgLFZfg5hLv7JtnGxzXZ93gd5s99G-b5spk7ORYpr%20Cv2tw8SBeNoZOg1J9N8Qm7kMQ5ACIw5iWFeAKSCkUhlHsShuAAsqel4YOe%20QBOhijgGaHAoVBURYbuJaaGAeEETIQjpKEQiQBUuHIRkUSRAaYhBox%20HNNB3F%20O%20Sp4QAHnwkDfqI5CHtQn7gLwAAK1RYEYRgADpGApJiVBwwl8ZAIlYbAxBWLp8hKHoAB2ACeqkAA7qVgmkhLeoh%20L8BZ%20sUkStH8to0VkWKdO5vCsQQBA%20Z5vxYqFfo0WxOA0QFBFec5WQFpxm6QVRzExU4CGEBBdhhMFIA5nsrjRZERVRSEmUvgVQgBdVkV1WcXFxVkj73nSoWcdV7Skeu-F%20vW760fM14GiaCCXqR2F2Dan6wAA%20jwi1IItoHwItCCrdAGCrYte0AMIGAA1hwz6xSknnMNJ35oH%205wAUBIFgWAHATYQl5sbNeqkMt5D7RtYBbTte1rcDf1-fJin2RwQA)

Comment: This is the most suitable solution for me. Here I can have dip switch for each output pin and when first nand gate output goes down I will shut down 5Mhz clock so the counter can can go to zero after reaching max, without any issues.

Comment: [CD4020B requires a supply voltage of *more* than 5 V to operate at 5 MHz](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/cd4020b.pdf?ts=1613126822473) (3.5 MHz at 5 V and 8 MHz at 10 V).

Comment: if it is an HC4020 , then you can get 73MHz @ 5V

Comment: Rev 1) removed inverter and Many input NAND, added SR latch for CLK selector, changed arbitrary clk1,2, added plots  https://tinyurl.com/y27n5yak

Answer (score 9):

You could use a binary adder on the 4020 output lines. Then use the output of the adder instead of the direct output. You'd need something like a bunch of DIP switches to set the offset (that gets added). Then, when the 4020 is reset, the adder's output becomes the value set by the DIP switches (or MCU or whatever).

Here's a typical 4-bit adder in case it is useful to you: -

[image]

Picture from [here](https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/combination/comb_7.html) and, that link also gives you more information on digital arithmetic that might help with your situation.

You should also note that with a carry-in and carry-out signal, these chips can be cascaded to 8 bits, 12 bits, 16 bits etc.: -

[image]

That picture is from [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/227701/design-8-bit-adder-with-74ls83/227714) but originally came from above.

Answer (score 1):

The CD4020 has no "preset" capability other than the RESET which sets it to all ZERO.  As far as "like CD4020" I'm not clear what that means but if it's actually like the CD4020 then the answer is the same.

Answer (score 0):

One crude solution to generate required number of pulses to set the count could be using following circuit
[image]

Suppose I want to set count 632. I'll press switch for 'a' timer 6 times, switch for 'b' 3 times and 'c' for 2 times.
For demonstration I used 1Hz, but frequency could be much higher and we can set timers a, b, c accordingly. I think, with proper calibration this could work.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for a "presettable" counter.  They have a set of inputs that can be transferred directly to the output with a "preset enable" signal.  The 4029 is presettable and I'm sure you can find it in other logic families.

Comment: You are right. But presentable counters have low range. One 14 stage binary counter can count more. Also, setting count is only one time requirement at the start of the device, then it is suppose to run till battery dies. Due  to the pandemic options are limited here.